# MersenneTwister random number generator

Tags: java, random, systemtime, mersenne-twister

I have a list(with 100.000 data) and i want to choose 4000 of them using MersenneTwister. I also want to use current system time because i run 15 times the program and i need different number of times.

```
MersenneTwister mt = new MersenneTwister("current system function");
for(int i=0; i<4000; i++){
    list1.add(mt.nextDouble());
}
```

I think that i must write something like this but i dont know which current system function to use to take different numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the no-argument form of the constructor.  Quoting the [javadocs at Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/math3/random/MersenneTwister.html#MersenneTwister()), "The instance is initialized using the current time plus the system identity hash code of this instance as the seed." Thus each run will produce different results.